# Convert Ballerina record into a JSON string

Tags: json, ballerina

```
type Student record {|
    string name;
    int id;
|};

Student student = {name: "Alex", id: 1};
```

Let's say I have a record type like this. How do we convert the record value `student` into a JSON string?

Answer (score 0):

```
import ballerina/io;

type Student record {|
    string name;
    int id;
|};

public function main() {
    Student student = {name: "Alex", id: 3};
    io:println(student.toJsonString());
}
```

We can use `toJsonString()` lang library to get the JSON string.